# Apps Script: Move Row based on option chosen in a drop down list

Tags: google-apps-script

**ISSUE:** I have a spreadsheet consisting of 5 sheets. The first sheet has in colum 6 a drop down list with following values/options:

1. "Completed"
2. "Work in progress"
3. "Approval required"
4. and "Done".

Anytime an option has been chosen from the drop down list, the row containing that active cell should be moved to another sheet. In other words:

1. If I choose "Completed", then the row must move to the sheet "Completed".
2. If I choose "Work in progress", then the row must move to the sheet "Work in progress", etc.

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:** My current script (see it below!) can do the moving part based on the option "Completed". Now the question is: How can I include the other options (so, "Work in progress", "Approval required" and "Done") into my drop down list, so that the related row can also be moved to the sheets they belong to?

Here is my current script:

```
// Names of sheets
var sourceSheet = "Master"
var destinationSheet = "Completed"

/* col: the column to watch,  x
 * changeVal: what value I want to change,
 * del: do I want to delete after the change?
 */

var check = {
  "col":6,
  "changeVal": "Completed",
  "del": false
  };

/* What I want to paste into the other sheet.
 * start: start column
 * cols: how many columns you want to copy
 */
var pasteRange = {
  "start": 1, 
  "cols": 6
  };
 

function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  
  if(sheet.getName() === sourceSheet){
    //Get active cell
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var cellCol = cell.getColumn();
    var cellRow = cell.getRow(); 
    
    if(cellCol === check.col){
      if(cell.getValue() === check.changeVal){
        
        //Select the range to export
        var exportRange = sheet.getRange(cellRow,pasteRange.start,1,pasteRange.cols);
        
        //Select the past destination
        var pasteDestination = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
        var pasteEmptyBottomRow = pasteDestination.getLastRow() + 1;
        
        //Copy the row to the new destination
        exportRange.copyTo(pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow,1),
                           SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
        
        //If delete is true delete after copying
        if(check.del){
          sheet.deleteRow(cellRow);
        };
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help :)

Comment: @Cooper: Any idea about the most efficient way to solve this issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the destination sheet by using the `value` property of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), and check that the sheet exists, like this:

```
function onEdit() {
  // ...
        const pasteDestination = ss.getSheetByName(e.value);
        if (!pasteDestination) {
          return;
        }
```

If you require more complex functionality in moving rows, take a look at the [moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/39992635?msgid=40432488) script. It is unfortunately too long to quote here directly.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!!!!

Comment: Just did it. Thank you so much :)